# What are the best ways to redirect user from page 01 to page 02 and then redirecting them to screen 01?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, user-expectation, user-centered-design

I am working on a feature where I have some constraints. To perform an operation on screen 01 I can't use a modal and have to redirect users to screen 02 for performing operations (As it involves complex operations and modal is not the best fit ) which is certainly unintuitive. How to achieve a seamless flow here?

[image: Screen 01]

[image: Screen 02]

After performing an operation on screen 02, the user needs to go back to 01. I am open to other suggestions apart from a separate page idea and modal.

Comment: Can you share more details about the kinds of operations, the current flow and what the exact problem is when redirecting between pages?

Comment: Hey solved this with an "in-page approach", not modal, not a page ~ came at a middle ground. Thanks for the interest :) I appreciate that